# Oracle 11 g Declare error

Tags: oracle11g

I'm learning to create a stored procedure in Oracle 11g and I'm using SQL Developer. When I ran the statement separately they work but when I group them together into a stored procedure and added some looping I got an error that I can't understand.
I'm not in luck when trying to search for the solution in the net so hoping anyone in this forum can offer some advice.
Thank you!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE InputAddr AS   
  DECLARE v_TotalCount INT;

  BEGIN
     -- this insert statement is correct and ran just fine
     INSERT INTO table1 (column1,colum2,colum3,...)
     SELECT column11,column12,column13,...
     FROM table2

     -- counting how many records have been inserted into table1
     select count(*) into v_totalcount
     from table1

     -- loop the process 
     IF v_totalcount >= 1000
     THEN
        WHILE v_TotalCount >= 1000
        LOOP
          DECLARE 
          P_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
          P_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200);
          P_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(200);

        BEGIN 
          P_NAME := 'TEST FILE';
          P_DESCRIPTION := 'TEST FILE DESC';
          P_COUNTRY := 'USA';

          INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES ( P_NAME, P_DESCRIPTION, P_COUNTRY );
          COMMIT; 
        END;            
        END LOOP;              
     ELSE
         -- less then 1000 run the same codes once
          DECLARE 
          P_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
          P_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200);
          P_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(200);            
        BEGIN 
          P_NAME := 'TEST FILE';
          P_DESCRIPTION := 'TEST FILE DESC';
          P_COUNTRY := 'USA';

          INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES ( P_NAME, P_DESCRIPTION, P_COUNTRY );
          COMMIT; 
        END;          
     END IF
  END;
```

Here is the error after compiling this procedure:

```
Error(3,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting 
one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
<an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor 
delete    exists prior external language
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need DECLARE on line 2.

"AS" acts as DECLARE here.

Comment: If I eliminated the DECLARE I got even more errors: Error(39,15): PLS-00201: identifier 'INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES' must be declared
Error(39,15): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(55,11): PLS-00201: identifier 'INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES' must be declared
Error(55,11): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(67,13): PLS-00201: identifier 'INSTANTADDRESS.GETADDRESSESRESULT' must be declared
Error(67,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored. By the way I added all the ; thank you!!

Comment: Please check if the user has EXECUTE privilege granted on the procedures/functions:  INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES, INSTANTADDRESS.GETADDRESSESRESULT, etc.

Comment: How do I check this priviledge? I know I have been made an admin

Comment: Try DESC INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES in Sql Developer and DESC INSTANTADDRESS

Comment: OK I got DESC INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES 
ERROR:                                      
------------------------------------------- 
ERROR: object SENDADDRESSES  does not exist 

DESC INSTANTADDRESS 
ERROR:                                      
------------------------------------------- 
ERROR: object INSTANTADDRESS does not exist 
so I don't have permission to execute, am I correct?

Comment: Correct. Since you are admin, try grant execute on <proc> to <user>

Comment: If I comment out: INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES ( P_NAME, P_DESCRIPTION, P_COUNTRY ); my procedure complied. So I know  the error is not due to the syntax. I checked and I have the privilidge. I'm using sql developer and I checked the location of  INSTANTADDRESS it is NOT located under the procedures or Functions but under "Other Users" I also tried adding EXECUTE such as this and still get the error: EXECUTE INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES ( P_NAME, P_DESCRIPTION, P_COUNTRY )

Comment: Under "Other Users", there is a list of users and one of those users owns `INSTANTADDRESS`. Let us call that user A. Say, user B is trying to compile this procedure `InputAddr`. A has to grant EXECUTE on `INSTANTADDRESS` to B. It seems `INSTANTADDRESS` is a package that has procedures such as `SENDADDRESSES`. Ultimately, B should be able to `DESC INSTANTADDRESS` and see procedures in that package, if necessary by specifying the fully qualified name, like `A.INSTANTADDRESS.SENDADDRESSES`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ramana's answer, you're also missing some semi-colons. Welcome to semi-colon hell, I mean, PL/SQL! *{:-)

I've added them in here, for you:

```
create or replace procedure inputaddr
as   
  v_totalcount int;
begin
  -- this insert statement is correct and ran just fine
  insert into table1 (column1,colum2,colum3,...)
  select column11,column12,column13,...
  from   table2; -- MISSING ; ADDED!

  -- counting how many records have been inserted into table1
  select count(*)
  into   v_totalcount
  from   table1; -- MISSING ; ADDED!

  -- loop the process 
  if v_totalcount >= 1000 then
    while v_totalcount >= 1000
    loop
      declare 
        p_name varchar2(200);
        p_description varchar2(200);
        p_country varchar2(200);
      begin 
        p_name := 'TEST FILE';
        p_description := 'TEST FILE DESC';
        p_country := 'USA';

        instantaddress.sendaddresses ( p_name, p_description, p_country );
        commit; 
      end;            
    end loop;              
  else
    -- less then 1000 run the same codes once
    declare 
      p_name varchar2(200);
      p_description varchar2(200);
      p_country varchar2(200);            
    begin 
      p_name := 'TEST FILE';
      p_description := 'TEST FILE DESC';
      p_country := 'USA';

      instantaddress.sendaddresses ( p_name, p_description, p_country );
      commit; 
    end;          
  end if; -- MISSING ; ADDED!
end inputaddr;
/
```